# How to align clickable regions with canvas when repositioning it in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I don't even know if I'm asking the question correctly. I have to host a third party game without using an iframe, but I have a hard requirement to include a banner for the hosting entity. That takes up 60 pixels at the top of the viewport that the code (which I do not have access to) was counting on using. That banner at the top causes the content to extend below the bottom of the viewport into overflow territory. So I add styling to the canvas element to compensate for the lost space at the top:

```
max-height:calc(100vh - 60px);
```

But that screws up the vertical centering, so I also need:

```
position:absolute;
top:60px;
```

There. Now all looks great. Until you need to point your mouse at something and you find that the only way you can click is to point it ~60px below the visible click target.

So my question is: How can I "trick" the code that I can't see into thinking that the viewport is 60px shorter (vertically) than it is in reality, so that the click regions line up with their visible counterparts?

Comment: Why can't you use an iframe?

Comment: Is it even possible to trick here? Considering the canvas takes the viewport for its origin, you can't trick it at all?!

Comment: Would it be worth it to simply overlay an intrusive banner? You could have the z-index be greater than that of the canvas, and it would be displayed over it, but not mess with anything else.

Comment: Ended up using an iframe. It just works.